# How to translate (i18n) error messages in actions with React, React Intl and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, internationalization, react-intl

I've a `performLogin` action, which triggers an API and tries to authenticate a user with the provided credentials. This API call can lead to errors. Her is my action:

```
export const performLogin = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        UsersAPI.login(email, password).then(response => {
            // [..]
        }).catch(error => {
            const definedError: Error = defaultError;
            switch (error.response.status) {
                case 401:
                    definedError.message = 'Invalid email or password';
                    break;
                default:
                    definedError.message = error.message;
            }
            dispatch(displayError(definedError));
        });
    };
};
```

My question is, how can I internationalize `Invalid email or password`?

I'm using [React Intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) so I have the infrastructure for i18n in the components. My idea is to define a error type, set it in the action and let the login component or a global error component decide, which error should be shown.

What is the React-Redux way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you trying to translate a message in action? Just save error key in store and pass it on `props` to `component` and use `FormattedMessage` to translate it when rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, that's what I'm planing. I just couldn't validate this approach anywhere.

Comment: No worries, I'm doing this in my projects. It works fine.